# What is a fast way to find two sets with equal sums in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, dynamic-programming, multimap

I need an efficient way to look through a list of sets of `ints` to see any two sets have the same sum. Specifically, in this case, I am generating the powerset of a list of ints that are given as an argument. From that powerset, I need to find a pair of subsets that sum to the same value.

Currently, I'm trying to use a dynamic programming approach (explanation below):

```
typedef std::vector<int> intvec;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > intvecvec;
typedef std::multimap<int,int> intmap;

/* Functions previously shown here that were removed:
 * intvecvec search_for_sum(intvec num_list)
 * and
 * int sum_exists(std::vector<intvec> pset, int index, intmap &sums)
 */

/* This function was previously just called powerset(), and wasn't
 * shown because the problem wasn't happening here. After refactoring,
 * I removed the functions that were shown here previously and simply
 * iteratively checked for sum matches while generating the powerset
 */
intvecvec powerset_search(intvec num_list)
{
    intvecvec result;
    std::multimap<int, intvec> power_set;
    for (int c = 0; c < pow(2, num_list.size()); c++) {
        intvec temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_list.size(); i++) {
            if (c & (1 << i)) {
                temp.push_back(num_list.at(i));
            }
        }
        int sum = std::accumulate( temp.begin(), temp.end(), 0 );
        std::multimap<int, intvec>::iterator it = power_set.find(sum);
        if (it == power_set.end()) {
            power_set.insert(std::make_pair(sum, temp));
        } else {
            result.push_back(it->second);
            result.push_back(temp);
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`search_for_sum()` creates the powerset of the given list of `ints`, along with a `multimap` called sums. For every element in the powerset, its sum is calculated. If that sum has not yet been encountered, the sum and the current index is inserted into `sums`. Otherwise, the current set and the one that had already been inserted into `sums` is returned.

This works. The problem is that for large sizes of `num_list`, this can take a few minutes to come back with a solution if there is one. This is significantly slower than the brute force method of just doing a double `for`-loop and calculating sums each time to find a match. Is there a better way for me to do this?

---

EDIT: So I was able to solve this by moving my sum-checking step up to when the powerset is actually being generated, iteratively checking all previously entered sums and returning if a match was found. But, as requested in the comments, I have also redone the problem description to (hopefully) remove the vagueness that was there initially.

Comment: "Specifically, in this case, I am looking through the powerset of some given sequence of integers, but in theory this would work for any list of sets." I think the *but* is misplaced. A "list of sets" implies some reasonably short list of arbitrary sets, while a powerset is very unreasonably large, usually, and is constrained by the original set. So this sounds like an X/Y-problem, that for your original problem X you have decided that solution Y with powerset must surely be The Thing, but hey, it turned out to be slow as molasses, so let's ask about it on SO. Better ask about the original X.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood the problem, create two arrays of sums, sort them and then a single pass will tell you which ones match.

Comment: Can you rephrase the original problem from the beginning?  There is ambiguity now and it's not clear.  Also you have dead code like `intsetvec` which is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by moving my sum-checking step up to when the powerset is actually being generated, iteratively checking all previously entered sums and returning if a match was found.